# Breaking apart one big XML into multiple tf resources

Tags: xml, terraform

I'm planning to create a terraform provider that builds a giant XML file. The service that consumes the XML file only has the 1 big giant XML file as a single resource. Inn the example below, this stitched up xml is the only resource.

```xml
<Main>
    <ChildA Id="childA">
        <GrandChildA></GrandChildA>
        <GrandChildA></GrandChildA>
        <GrandChildA></GrandChildA>
    </ChildA>
    <ChildB Id="childB">
        <GrandChildB>
            <GreatGrandChildB></GreatGrandChildB>
        </GrandChildB>
    </ChildB>
</Main>
```

I wanted to break this apart into smaller pieces, but `ChildA` and `ChildB` aren't actual resources in the service and is just part of `Main`. I can't find any examples in the [hashicups provider example](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-hashicups), and from what i noticed from other providers like `aws`, `azure`, `kubernetes` the resources represent an actual resource in the service.

```
resource "main_element" "main_1" {
   childA = child_a_element.child_a_1
   childB = child_b_element.child_b_1
} 

resource "child_a_element" "child_a_1" {
   id = "childA"
   ... other config here
}

resource "child_b_element" "child_b_1" {
   id = "childB"
   ... other config here
}
```

How do i go about implementing this? Should they be `resources` or should they be `data_sources`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the examples so generalized I'm not sure I'm fully understanding the situation, but I think what you are saying is that the remote API models this whole "Main" object, including all of its sub-items, as a single unit that must be created, updated, and destroyed together.

If that is true, then the most appropriate representation for it in Terraform would be a single resource type with nested blocks representing each of the nested elements in the XML.

It's not generally practical to split a single remote object across multiple Terraform resources because each resource has a separate lifecycle and so providers can't directly coordinate the handling of multiple resource instances together as a single operation. The role of a Terraform provider is typically to just adapt the underlying API design to fit Terraform's model, rather than to create significant new abstractions on top of the underlying API concepts.

The particular XML structure you've defined here is actually quite a nice fit for a nested block type represented as a map, using the map keys as the `Id` attributes in your XML:

```
resource "main" "example" {
  child_a "childA" {
    grandchild_a {
    }

    grandchild_a {
    }

    grandchild_a {
    }
  }

  child_b "childB" {
    grandchild_b {
      great_grandchild_b {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this structure where a nested block type accepts a label and gets represented as a map is not supported in the current version of the Terraform SDK (v2.2.0 is current at the time I'm writing this). That capability was added in Terraform v0.12.0 and the SDK only recently dropped backward-compatibility support for Terraform v0.11, so it doesn't support that structure yet.

Therefore the closest approximation of that in the current SDK would be for `child_a` and `child_b` to both be defined as `TypeSet` and have a nested required argument for the id, like this:

```
resource "main" "example" {
  child_a {
    id = "childA"

    grandchild_a {
    }

    grandchild_a {
    }

    grandchild_a {
    }
  }

  child_b "child" {
    id = "childB"

    grandchild_b {
      great_grandchild_b {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

(For completeness: at the time I'm writing this, the Terraform SDK team at HashiCorp is working on [a new foundational library](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go) that implements the low-level Terraform plugin protocol with all of the currently-supported features of that protocol. It's at a *much* lower level of abstraction than the v2 SDK, but intended to be used as the foundations for a future SDK version that supports new features. It's experimental at the time I'm writing this but I'm mentioning it both because this answer will probably still be here once it *stops* being experimental, and because for providers with unique needs it may be helpful to implement against this lower-level API, if the higher-level abstractions are getting in the way.)

Comment: Figures, i ended up with this same conclusion that the i'll only have a single resource littered with ``TypeSets``. I was thinking about abstracting these as data sources in the provider and just keeping a singleton map there, but that really feels hacky. 

To add context i'm trying to build a provider around Azure B2C IEF policies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/trustframeworkpolicy, really wanted to break this apart because my base policy is now around 5k lines long ( which is the same that you'd find in their actual examples ).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure B2C IEF policies, but the situation you've described sounds similar to a case with AWS IAM Policies, where the Terraform provider has a data source [`aws_iam_policy_document`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) that can take an existing policy document as input and return a new version with items added. Perhaps a similar design would suit your situation too.

Comment: thank you, i'll look into that. out of curiosity can ``TypeSets`` be broken down into data sources?